# Optional Parameters causing a InternalErrorException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm starting to use Optional parameters (as I came from java and haven't ever experimented with them before) and I'm running into the following issue:

```
Unhandled Exception: Mono.CSharp.InternalErrorException: Internal error

  at Mono.CSharp.MethodGroupExpr.IsApplicable (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Arguments& arguments, Int32 arg_count, System.Reflection.MethodBase& method, System.Boolean& params_expanded_form) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.MethodGroupExpr.OverloadResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Arguments& Arguments, Boolean may_fail, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.New.DoResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, ResolveFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Assign.DoResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.SimpleAssign.DoResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, ResolveFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ExpressionStatement.ResolveStatement (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.StatementExpression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Block.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.If.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Block.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.FlowBranching parent, Mono.CSharp.BlockContext rc, Mono.CSharp.ParametersCompiled ip, IMethodData md) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The code causing this issue is here:

```
Me = new UserAccount(
    name: response["first_name"] as string,
    age:  DateToAge(response["birthday"] as string),
    facebookID: response["id"] as string,
    email: response["email"] as string,
    gender: (response["gender"] as string == "male") ? 0 : 1
);
```

Where "response" is a `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
Dictionary<string, object> response = FacebookHelper.Deserialize(jsonString);
```

And the UserAccount class is here:

```
public class UserAccount {
    public string SessionKey;
    public string FacebookID;
    public string Name;
    public string Email;
    public int Age;
    public int Gender; 
    public GeoLocation Location;
    public Texture Avatar;

    public UserAccount(string name, int age, int gender, string email = "", GeoLocation location = null, string sessionKey = "", string facebookID = "",  Texture avatar = null) {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
        Location = location;
        SessionKey = sessionKey;
        FacebookID = facebookID;
        Avatar = avatar;
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the correct direction of resolving this?

Comment: When are you getting the error - when you build, or when you run? Which version of Mono are you using, and on what platform? Can you provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem? (Ideally cut down the number of parameters involved to a minimum.) As a side-note, I'd strongly advise you to avoid using public fields, and if "gender" only has two values, consider making it a `bool` called `isMale` or something similar, or have an enum...

Comment: @JonSkeet - The error is at compile time, as for the version of mono I'm completely clueless, I'm using the UnityEngine (5) and I believe they have their own mono fork.

Comment: If you're using Unity, that's *very* important information, which should be in the question. A short but complete example would still be very useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Gender is classified as an integer because we support the option to pick transsexual as-well in our application, but I haven't gotten to the point as to where it's relevant yet so it was just left out. -- I'll write a simple example and see if the error persists.

Comment: If it needs more values, you should be using an enum. An int is not a good fit here, IMO

Answer (score 1):

This is a genuine compiler error that's been there for a long time. Unity uses a fork of an old and buggy version of Mono. It happens because of named parameters. Personally, I was able to use named parameters sometimes, but in some cases it just crashed on a completely correct code. Unfortunately, the only advice I can give you is not to use named parameters with Unity Mono compiler.

Comment: God bless! You saved my sanity. Thank you so much for that.